# How to scan 2-dimensional char array in c

Tags: c

I want to get string(including white spaces)input save to 2-dimensional array.
my code is this :

```
char a[10000][6];
scanf("%d", &n);
for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
    scanf("%[^\n]s", a[i]);
}

for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", a[i]);
}
```

What I got that is wrong output.Please give me any suggestion!

Comment: *"but what I got is wrong output"* - dare I ask (a) what *exact* input you were *reading*, (b) what *exact* output you were *expecting*, and (c) what *exact* output you were *actually getting*. *All* of that information belongs *in your question*.

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` what do you think this will do? Look up in tbe documentation, don't guess.

Comment: a) scanf("%d",&n) -> number of input(a line) to get , scanf("%[^\n]s", a[i]); -> line such as "push 1" (can include space) / b) i expect to get output "push 1"(exactly same as input)/ c)  when i made input 3  (number of input to get), output was 儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆儆 儆     wrong characters...

Comment: @jenny don't put updates in comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY %9999?

Comment: @jenny what you are missing is there should be no `s` at the end of `"%[^\n]s"` (unless you intent to terminate input art the first `'s'`). The proper format specifier to read up to the `'\n'` is simply `"%[^\n]"` (the *character class* is the *format specifier* used in lieu of `'s'`) Now you still must account for the `'\n'` left in the *input buffer* (e.g. `stdin`) so you will generally want `"%[^\n]%*c"` to *read up to the* `'\n'` and then *read and discard the following character* (e.g. the `'\n'`). The `'*'` is called the *assignment suppression operator*. (see `man scanf`)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
char a[10000][6];
scanf("%d",&n);
int i;
for (i = 0;i < n;i++)
{
scanf("%s",&a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this question in my program. I came to the conclusion that the best way to read input from keyboard is to handle character one by one. You can use code below.:

```
bool in()
{
    int i;
    int a;
    int len;
    int max;
    char *text[10000];

    //change 'max' somehow here before loop

    for(i = 0, len = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        text[i] = NULL;

        do  
        {
            do
            {
                a = getchar();
            }
            while(a == '\n' && !text[i]);

            if(text[i])
            {
                len = strlen(text[i]);
                len++;
            }
            else
            {
                len = 1;
            }

            text[i] = realloc(text[i], sizeof(char)*(len+1));
            if(!text[i])
            {
                printf("cant realloc\n");
                return false;
            }

            if(a != '\n')
            {
                text[i][len-1] = (char) a; 
                text[i][len] = '\0'; 
            }
            else
            {
                text[i][len-1] = '\0'; 
            }
        }
        while(a != '\n');
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Or use a *line-oriented* input function (e.g. `fgets`) and simply remove the trailing `'\n'` that is *read and included* in the buffer. (both `fgets` and POSIX `getline` work the same in that regard).

Comment: Fgets() has disadvantage. In case there is repeating input and user put in longer string than fgets() allows, then strange behavior follows in next expected input. Programmer has to know how many characters user will put in. But programmer never knows.

Comment: No, not really, that is why you **validate** with `size_t len = strlen (buf); if (buf[len - 1] != '\n') { ...line too long...}`.

Comment: Now I understand that, fgets() is possible solution.

Comment: Here is a recent answer that puts that check, and a couple of more, into insuring a specific character limit fits within a short array [fgets error check example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43964879/c-populating-one-char-array-using-fscanf-changes-the-value-of-another-char-arra/43965723?noredirect=1#comment74962401_43965723)