# Populating one char array using fscanf changes the value of another char array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm first using fscanf to populate my first array then again using fscanf from the same input file to populate another array.  However this seems to be shifting the values in my first array.

Here is my input:

```
4 
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz12
3456
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prints( int n, char sqr[n][n]){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%c", sqr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void){

    FILE *in = fopen("transform.in", "r");
    FILE *out = fopen("transform.out", "w");

    int num;
    fscanf(in, "%d", &num);

    char square[num][num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        fscanf(in, "%s", square[i]);
    }

    prints(num, square);
    printf("\n");

    char endSquare[num][num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        fscanf(in, "%s", endSquare[i]);
    }

    fclose(in);

    prints(num, square);
    printf("\n");

    prints(num, endSquare);
    printf("\n");

    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output I get:

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

bcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

qrst
uvwx
yz12
3456
```

As you can see my square array seems to be changed after I populate endSquare.

Comment: `fscanf(in, "%s", square[i])` This writes 5 characters, not 4: `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and the terminating `\0`. The first 4 go into `square[0][0]` through `square[0][3]`. The last one overflows into `square[1][0]`. On the last iteration of the loop, with `i == num-1`, you have a buffer overrun whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Where is the space for the *nul-terminating* character that `%s` will attempt to append to the end of each `square[i]` and `endSquare[i]`. Looks like *Undefined Behavior*....

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, *"great minds think alike"* `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to not accounting for the *nul-terminating* character that the `%s` format specifier will append, you are making things extremely hard on yourself by attempting to read **lines** of data with a **formatted input** function `fscanf`. When doing *line-oriented* input, it is far better to use a *line-oriented* input function such as `fgets` and then parse the needed information from the buffer containing the entire line of information. Why? Mixing numeric and character input with the `scanf` family of functions can pose many traps for those who do not account for all characters that remain in the *input buffer* or account for how the differing `fscanf` *format specifiers* handle leading *whitespace*.

Particularly, in your case when reading `num`, you have no way to limit the number of characters read by `fscanf` using the `%s` *format specifier*. You cannot include a variable *field width* to protect against writing beyond your array bounds. (e.g. you **can't** use something like `%nums` for `%4s` to insure you limit the characters read to `4`) When using a VLA to hold a specific number of characters based on what is read from the first line, there just isn't an elegant way to incorporate `num` and validate/limit the number of characters read using `fscanf`.

All of this adds up to a *train-wreck* waiting to happen if there happens to be a stray `space` (or other character) at the end of one of your lines.

So, how to handle reading only `4-char` into each row of `square` and `endsquare`? (**note:** the capital `'S'` was reduced to lower-case to match normal C-style) When you need to handle lines of input, use a line oriented input function and provide a buffer sufficient to handle each line of data. I would rather use a `128-char` buffer and insure I read every `4-5 char line` than accidentally read a `5-char` line into a `4-char` buffer -- to avoid **Undefined Behavior**. Moreover, you can use the same buffer to read every line of data.

Next, you must **validate** every read and every conversion to insure you do not process garbage from the point of the failed read or failed conversion forward in your code. For example, when reading your data file, you can declare a simple buffer and read your first line as follows:

```
#define MAX 128
...
    char buf[MAX] = "";
    ...
    if (!fgets (buf, MAX, in)) {    /* read 1st line with 'num' */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read of 'num' failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;          /* errno to check after strtol conversion */
    int num = (int)strtol (buf, NULL, 10);  /* convert num to int */
    if (errno) {        /* validate */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed conversion of 'num'.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

When reading each subsequent line, you need to confirm that the *entire-line* was read by checking for the trailing `'\n'` (read and included by `fgets`) and if it isn't present, your line is too long (handle error). You also need to know if there are `num` characters in the line *since you are NOT storing the lines as strings* (only as a character array). If there are not `num-chars` read, you cannot copy `num-chars` to `square[i]` or `endsquare[i]`. Since you are using a `for` loop, you also must check that each line you read is a valid line. Just because you read `4` as line one, there is no guarantee there are `8` lines in the file. (you would ideally want to use a `while (fgets (buf, MAX, in))` loop to drive the rest of the input and a counter to break after `4-lines` are read, but you can protect within the `for` loop by validating with an `if (fgets (buf, MAX, in))` as well.

With that in mind, you could fill the character arrays with exactly `4-chars` read from the file (or less) while checking for any unexpected empty lines with something like the following while still using your `for` loop:

```
    char square[num][num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        size_t len, n = num;
        if (!fgets (buf, MAX, in))      /* read line int buf */
            break;                      /* break if no line read */
        len = strlen (buf);             /* get length */
        if (buf[len - 1] != '\n') {     /* if no '\n' at end, too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line[%d] too long.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (*buf == '\n') {             /* 1st char is '\n' - empty */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: empty line encountered.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ((int)(len - 1) < num)       /* if less than num, reduce num */
            n = len - 1;
        memcpy (square[i], buf, n);     /* copy 'num' chars from buf */
    }
```

You can do the same for your `endsquare` loop. Putting it all together, you could do something like the following (**note:** `out` is unused, so the code related to it is commented out below):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX 128

void prints (int n, char (*sqr)[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            putchar (sqr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAX] = "";
    FILE *in = fopen (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "transform.in", "r");
    // FILE *out = fopen ("transform.out", "w");

    if (!in /* || !out */) {  /* validate both files open */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(fgets (buf, MAX, in))) {  /* read 1st line with 'num' */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read of 'num' failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    errno = 0;          /* errno to check after strtol conversion */
    int num = (int)strtol (buf, NULL, 10);  /* convert num to int */
    if (errno) {        /* validate */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: failed conversion of 'num'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char square[num][num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        size_t len, n = num;
        if (!fgets (buf, MAX, in))      /* read line int buf */
            break;                      /* break if no line read */
        len = strlen (buf);             /* get length */
        if (buf[len - 1] != '\n') {     /* if no '\n' at end, too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line[%d] too long.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (*buf == '\n') {             /* 1st char is '\n' - empty */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: empty line encountered.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ((int)(len - 1) < num)       /* if less than num, reduce num */
            n = len - 1;
        memcpy (square[i], buf, n);     /* copy 'num' chars from buf */
    }

    prints (num, square);
    putchar ('\n');

    char endsquare[num][num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        size_t len, n = num;
        if (!fgets (buf, MAX, in))      /* read line int buf */
            break;                      /* break if no line read */
        len = strlen (buf);             /* get length */
        if (buf[len - 1] != '\n') {     /* if no '\n' at end, too long */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: line[%d] too long.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        if (*buf == '\n') {             /* 1st char is '\n' - empty */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: empty line encountered.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if ((int)(len - 1) < num)       /* if less than num, reduce num */
            n = len - 1;
        memcpy (endsquare[i], buf, n);  /* copy 'num' chars from buf */
    }

    fclose(in);

    prints (num, square);
    putchar ('\n');

    prints (num, endsquare);
    putchar ('\n');

    // fclose(out);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** never use the variadic `printf` function to output a single-character, instead, use a function designed to output a single character like `putchar` (or `fputc`). And also note, you should preserve the count of individual lines and pass the correct number to `prints` in the event there are less than `num` lines read in any group (that is left for you).

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/list.txt
4
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
uvwx
yz12
3456
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/inout dat/list.txt
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop

qrst
uvwx
yz12
3456
```

There are always more validations you can do, but at a minimum something like the above will work for your data with reasonable error checking. Look things over and let me know if you have any questions.

If you want to print **squares**, you could always do something like the following:

```
void prints (int n, char (*sqr)[n])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (j)
                putchar (' ');
            putchar (sqr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
}
```

**Example w/Modified** `prints`

```
$ ./bin/inout dat/list.txt
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p

a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
m n o p

q r s t
u v w x
y z 1 2
3 4 5 6
```

Comment: It would be possible to use `char format[8]; …; snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%%ds", num);` and then use `format` in place of `"%s"` in the calls to `scanf()` to limit the input to `num` characters.  You just have to ignore (or suppress) the warnings about 'non-literal formats' from over-zealous compilers.

Comment: Now my brain didn't go there, that's a pretty creative way to make sure you only shoehorn `num` characters into your array. I bet `-pedantic` would love it `:)`

Comment: It's `-Wformat-nonliteral` that has conniptions.  The downside of the approach is that if your input line is longer than 4 characters plus newline, those extra characters are simply read the next time you call `scanf()`.  On the whole, I think it is better to use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or even
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read whole lines (use a size like 4096 — or something significantly bigger than 80) and then check whether you got garbage or not